# How to create a Nestjs module based on async config?

Tags: asynchronous, nestjs, config

I'm trying to create a DB module like so:

```
const dbProvider = {
  provide: 'DB',
  useFactory: async (configService:ConfigService) => {
    const dbUrl = configService.get<string>('DB_URL')
    return Knex({
      client: 'pg',
      connection: dbUrl
    })
  },
  inject: [ConfigService]
}

@Module({
  providers: [ConfigService, dbProvider],
  exports: [dbProvider],
})
export class DbModule {}
```

This is the AppModule definition:

```
@Module({
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [Logger, AppService, {
    provide: ConfigService,
    useFactory: getConfigFactory(['DB_URL']),
  }],
  exports: [ConfigService]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

and:

```
export function getConfigFactory(paramsToLoad: string[]) {
    return async () => {await getConfigService(paramsToLoad)}
}
export async function getConfigService(paramsToLoad: string[]) {

    const paramStoreParams = await loadParamStore(paramsToLoad)
    return new ConfigService(paramStoreParams)
}
```

loadParamStore uses SSM to fetch parameters from SSM

The issue is, that when the DB setup is performed (above), the ConfigService only contains the envs taken from .env, DB_URL is only loaded at a later stage (verified), so at the time of building knex, DB_URL is not yet available.

Is there a correct Nestjs way to achieve such functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, start by removing your custom `getConfigFactory()` and `getConfigService()` functions. You should not create the `ConfigService` instance yourself. It is instantiated for you by importing the `ConfigModule`. Sure, you can new it up yourself and pass it data, but that's meant for internal usage by the `ConfigModule`.

If you want to load configuration from an external source, SSM in your case, then use the custom configuration file feature.

https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#custom-configuration-files

Add a new file, e.g. `external-config.ts` to your project. Here you can code how to load your external configuration. It should return a factory function that returns a configuration object.

```
export interface SsmConfiguration {
  database: {
    url: string;
  };
}

export async function loadExternalConfiguration(): Promise<SsmConfiguration> {
  // Load the configuration from SSM here.
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve({
        database: {
          url: 'localhost',
        },
      });
    }, 1000);
  });
}
```

By the way, this can still be combined with `.env` files.

Next import the `ConfigModule` as a global module in the `AppModule`. This way its providers (`ConfigService`) can be used in other modules without having to re-import the `ConfigModule`. Use its `forRoot()` method and specify the custom factory function created earlier in the `load` option.

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      // You can specify multiple config factory functions.
      load: [loadExternalConfiguration],
    }),
    DbModule
    ...
  ]
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [...]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Last, but not least inject the `ConfigService` in the factory function that returns the `Knex` instance. At that time you should be able to read the configuration the `ConfigService` has read for you. Just make sure to use the correct dotted notation to access the properties of the configuration object returned by your custom factory function.

```
@Module({
  imports: [],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: DB_TOKEN,
      useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => {
        const url = config.get<string>('database.url');
        return Knex({...})
      },
      inject: [ConfigService],
    },
  ],
  exports: [DB_TOKEN],
})
export class DbModule {}
```

If you run the application you'll notice a 1s delay during the startup when its simulating a delay when "fetching" the configuration.

You can now inject the provider identified by the `DB` token in your providers that are part of the `AppModule`.

Comment: I have edited the post to better explain the issue

Comment: Ah, I understand your problem better now. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, this is actually the first thing I tried, but the issue is that the promise is resolved after Knex is built (tried it with debugger). I think the issue is that @nestjs/config load property doesn't expect an async function.

Comment: My factory function above uses async / await and a timeout to simulate resolving a value. Take a look at the config.module.ts code of the @nest/config module: https://github.com/nestjs/config/blob/b7633aa5b97ead18a4ae5a87973985d191c624dd/lib/config.module.ts#L82. It converts those factory functions you pass via the load option to providers. Sounds like you are missing an await somewhere.

Comment: So your code does work. What made the difference was that I listed ConfigService in the DbModule Providers. Once I removed it things started working in the correct order. I'm not sure why this matters.

Comment: Ah, that will cause NestJS to create a new singleton instance of the ConfigService in the context of your DB module which is then in turn injected in the factory function for your Knex provider. This instance of the ConfigService of course knows nothing about the custom configuration that you load. That is loaded in your AppModule by another ConfigService instance.

Answer (score 5):

So I faced a similar problem. My problem Statement was - **Load AWS Secrets in Nest JS.** This had to be done before any other module is instantiated. Example - TypeORM, JWT Module both required config values.

How I achieved it? By building a helper function which fetches secrets from AWS and persists those values in process.env

```
export async function secretLoader(){
  const secretsManager = new SecretsManager({
    region: process.env['AWS_REGION'],
  });
  const secretsIds = [process.env['AWS_SECRET_ID']];

  const commands = secretsIds.map(
    (secretId) =>
      new GetSecretValueCommand({
        SecretId: secretId,
      }),
  );
  const resp = commands.map((command) =>
    secretsManager.send(command),
  );
  const secrets = await Promise.all(resp);
  const response = secrets.reduce((acc, secret) => {
    const sec = JSON.parse(<string>secret.SecretString);
    return {
      ...acc,
      ...sec,
    };
  }, {});
  Object.keys(response).forEach((key) => {
    process.env[key] = response[key];
  });
}
```

You just need to set 2 properties in env files - 'AWS_REGION' and 'AWS_SECRET_ID'

Next, in the main.ts file. Import and Run this function.

```
import { secretLoader } from './secretLoader';

async function bootstrap() {
  await secretLoader();
  initializeTransactionalContext(); // Initialize cls-hooked
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  const configService: ConfigService = app.get(ConfigService);
  await app.listen(configService.get<number>('PORT') || 3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

Cheers!

PS -
I tried using config factory method in 'load'. But it doesn't work since some modules initialised before config module.